# How to join and select from tables with conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables and wanna to join and get sum fields with aggression.

My tables are:

[image]

That "PriceListid" in tables are same ( join fields)

So, I want to find Users("UserID") and "Price" but with "Type=0(viewed) or 1(clicked) " and also get SUM("ShowQuantity"), Sum("ClickQuantity) and "Title","URL",... 
The results should grouped by "UserID".

The results would be like this:

[image]

Comment: What are the table names ?

Comment: In image Price column present in both the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new information in your comments, the main table can be used to find which user viewed/clicked on which offer how many times:

```
select 
    pl.userid, 
    pl.PriceListId, 
    pl.offerid,
    sum(case when pl.type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'times_viewed',
    sum(case when pl.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'times_clicked'
from PriceList pl
group by pl.userid, pl.PriceListId, pl.offerid
having sum(case when pl.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Then expanding this base query, you can join to the second table to get `title` and `url`:

```
select 
    pl.userid, 
    pl.pricelistid, 
    pl.offerid,
    sum(case when pl.type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'times_viewed',
    sum(case when pl.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'times_clicked',
    max(pld.Title) as 'Title',
    max(pld.URL) as 'URL',
    max(pld.Model) as 'Name'
from PriceList pl
inner join PriceListDetails pld on pld.OfferId = pl.OfferId and pld.pricelistid = pl.pricelistid
group by pl.userid, pl.pricelistid, pl.offerid
having sum(case when pl.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

To further filter this to only show records where `PriceListId` meets certain criteria as described in your comments, this should work:

```
select 
    pl.userid, 
    pl.pricelistid, 
    pl.offerid,
    sum(case when pl.type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'times_viewed',
    sum(case when pl.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'times_clicked',
    max(pld.Title) as 'Title',
    max(pld.URL) as 'URL',
    max(pld.Model) as 'Name'
from PriceList pl
inner join PriceListDetails pld on pld.OfferId = pl.OfferId and pld.pricelistid = pl.pricelistid
where pl.pricelistid in (
    select articleid
    from c
    where c.state = 2
    and c.Created >= datediff(dd,0,getdate())
)
group by pl.userid, pl.pricelistid, pl.offerid
having sum(case when pl.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, for additional information I attached 2 screenshot of my data: [link](http://prntscr.com/cbbbs9)  and  [link](http://prntscr.com/cbbcfx) first one that you named "pl" table and second screenshot is "pld". So, as you see I want to find users ("userID") who viewed "A" and also clicked on "A" - ("A in here is "PriceListId"- and filed 'Type' consist 0 for viewed and 1 clicked) , and also I want find (count) how many times viewed ('offerid')  is same column. for example user X may be visited 4 times for A (same 'offerid') but just clicked  one times.

Comment: I attached another screenshot about what I explained in last comment, it's for one user, [link](http://prntscr.com/cbbht3)! As you see I want to find how many times this user(all users in main table) visited on same 'offerId' and also clicked on that!  in this screen shot the result will be "offerid 9041- 1 time viewed 1 time clicked"or for offerid= 93359, 2 times viewed 1 times clicked-

Comment: @yadishahryary I've updated my answer based on your comments, please let me know if this is closer to what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much but first script is work correctly because according to my screen shot the results is correct but when I want to 'Title' and 'Url' ,etc from table ('pld') when I'm executed your second script I got [link](http://prntscr.com/cbc5vm) screenshot, that's incorrect! ('times view'& 'times clicked')! what do you think if we join with 'Offerid'? there are same in 2 tables and we found it in your first script!! once again I shared full table structures [link](http://prntscr.com/cbc7a8) - ( left one is "pl" and right one is "pld" ). Thanks

Comment: @yadishahryary ah ok, that's because there are multiple records for the same `PriceListId` in "pld". I didn't spot that earlier. Is `OfferId` unique in "pld"? Then yes, joining on `OfferId` should give you the correct result. Try the updated second query.

Comment: Also, please provide a screenshot of the "pld" table with `OfferId` values displayed. I think we might need to join on both `PriceListId` and `OfferId` if that is the unique combination on the second table.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot one rule- script above it's for 'offerid' it's mean who viewed and who clicked on same 'offerid'. Now, I want to see from your first script "Who viewed A also Clicked A"  'A' in here is 'PricelistId' it's mean according to the [link] (http://prntscr.com/cbcezv) I should be have one user and one 'PriceListId' !! ( if you see last 2 record in screenshot, the users just viewed 'Type=0' and Not clicked ! so, I have just one record from this table! how I can update this script by new rule? thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122036/discussion-between-rohitvats-and-yadi-shahryary).